# Запись полученных данных в таблицу базы данных

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

**Условие такое**: есть фабрика фигур, где на основе одного абстрактного класса наследуются 3 разные геометрические фигуры, для которых просчитывается цвет, площадь, периметр. В классе запуска пользователь с консоли вводит цифру и генерирует одну из фигур.

**Проблемы**:

1. Цвет каждой фигуры определяется выборкой рандомного элемента из таблицы базы данных. Никак не могу понять как обратиться к полю в таблице, чтобы оттуда вытащить цвет для нашей фигуры.
2. Все сгенерированные фигуры должны записываться во вторую таблицу базы данных. Итого у нас 2 таблицы: одна `Colors` - с цветами, откуда читаем, вторая `Shapes` – куда все пишется (поля: `id`, `circle`, `perimeter`, `square`).

Код, который есть сейчас:

1.

```
public abstract class ShapeFactory {

    String name;
    String color;
    double perimeter;
    double area;

    ShapeFactory() {
    }

    abstract void findP();
    abstract void findA();
}
```

2.

```
class Circle extends ShapeFactory {

    int radius;

    public Circle(int radius) {
        this.name = "Circle";
        this.color = ???;
        this.radius = radius ;
        findP();
        findA();
        getInfo();
    }   

    @Override
    void findP() {
        this.perimeter = 2 * Math.PI * radius ;
    }

    @Override
    void findA() {
        this.area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        if (this.area > 50) {
            this.color = "Red";
        }
    }

    void getInfo() {
        System.out.println("Your shape is " + this.name + "; Your color is " + this.color + "; Perimeter = " + this.perimeter + "; Area = " + this.area);    
    }
}
```

3.

```
class Square extends ShapeFactory {

    int squareSide;

    public Square(int squareSide) {
        this.name = "Square";
        this.color = "White";
        this.squareSide = squareSide ;
        findP();
        findA();
        getInfo();
    }

    @Override
    void findP() {
        this.perimeter = 4 * squareSide ;
    }

    @Override
    void findA() {
        this.area = Math.pow(squareSide, 2);
        if (this.area > 50) {
            this.color = "Red";
        }
    }

    void getInfo() {
        System.out.println("Your shape is " + this.name + "; Your color is " + this.color + "; Perimeter = " + this.perimeter + "; Area = " + this.area);    
    }
}
```

4.

```
class Triangle extends ShapeFactory {

    int side1;
    int side2;
    int side3;

    public Triangle(int side1, int side2, int side3) {
        this.name = "Triangle";
        this.color = "White";
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;        
        findP();
        findA();
        getInfo();
    }

    @Override
    void findP() {
        this.perimeter = side1 + side2 + side3;
    }

    @Override
    void findA() {
        double semiperimeter = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
        this.area = Math.sqrt(semiperimeter * (semiperimeter - side1) * (semiperimeter - side2) * (semiperimeter - side3));
        if (this.area > 50) {
            this.color = "Red";
        }
    }

    void getInfo() {
        System.out.println("Your shape is " + this.name + "; Your color is " + this.color + "; Perimeter = " + this.perimeter + "; Area = " + this.area);        
    }
```

5.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PlayShapeFactory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Colors colors = new Colors();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number from 1 to 3");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        switch (number) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You`ve chosen circle. Enter radius");
            int radius = sc.nextInt();
            new Circle(radius);
            st.execute("Insert into 'shapes' values(1, 'Red')");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You`ve chosen square. Enter square side");
            int squareSide = sc.nextInt();
            new Square(squareSide);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You`ve chosen triangle. Enter three triangle sides");
            int side1 = sc.nextInt();
            int side2 = sc.nextInt();
            int side3 = sc.nextInt();
            new Triangle(side1, side2, side3);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong, enter number from 1 to 3");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

6.

```
public class Colors {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection bd = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection bd = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D://Colors.db");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Statement st = bd.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("Drop table colors");
        st.executeUpdate("Create table colors (id INT, color VARCHAR)");
        st.execute("Insert into colors values(1, 'Red')");
        st.execute("Insert into colors values(2, 'Green')");
        st.execute("Insert into colors values(3, 'Blue')");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from colors");


        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(rs.getInt(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println("--");
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        bd.close();
    }
```

Comment: Я, кстати, не досчитался закрывающих сам класс фигурных скобок у классов `Triangle` и `Colors`.

Comment: да это я криво скопировала, сорри

Comment: @Regent когда я исправлял через какое то время система не дала сохранить изменение. И получилось безвыходное положение, не сохранить не вернутся. и пришлось закрыть правку. Если нужно могу отменить свою правку, так как Вашу я потом увидел, был лучше.

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev по идее, лучше откатить и добавить ваши изменения заново, поверх моих. Классов, кстати, 6, а цифр у вас 4 было - деление было не по классам?

Comment: @Regent не получается удалить правку. как это сделать?

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev да вот в том и проблема, что при наличии 1000 репутации это бы можно было быстро сделать: и откатить бы, и объединить бы вручную. В текущей ситуации, видимо, нужно вручную всё переделать. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @Regent Спасибо, Вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Способов решения вашей задачи - великое множество. Самый кошерный - это завести вашу задачу под какой-нибудь ORM фреймворк типа [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/).

Но, судя по всему, для вас это будет неподъёмно. Так что придётся по-простому.

Запомните 2 простые вещи о соответствии Java объектов и SQL данных:

1. Класс - это таблица в БД SQL, где поля таблицы - это члены класса.
2. Запись в таблице - это объект.

В соответствии с этим, вам надо создать таблицы по количеству ваших фигур и определить в каждом из ваших классов простые методы вставки/сохранения в БД данных и, соответственно, получения.

Comment: Для данной простой задачи Hibernate будет лишним, ИМХО. Уж лучше JOOQ заюзать.